# Rails 4 "Template is missing" error with jasper-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasper-reports

I have installed the jasper-rails 1.0.3 and followed the instructions as per https://github.com/fortesinformatica/jasper-rails. My java installation is fine.

Here is my controller code:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :pdf

  def index
    @council_report = CouncilReport.find(params[:council_report_id])
  end

  def proposed_works_summary
    @council_report = CouncilReport.find(params[:council_report_id])
    @proposed_works_summary = proposed_works_summary_data(@council_report.id)
    respond_with @proposed_works_summary
  end
end
```

My routes.rb:

```
...
resources :reports, only: [:index] do
  member do
    get 'proposed_works_summary'
  end
end
...
```

Here is the error in the browser:

> Template is missing
>
> > Missing template reports/proposed_works_summary, application/proposed_works_summary with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "d:/Users/Michael/Documents/Aptana Workspace/cam/app/views"

Now I obviously have a proposed_works_summary.jrxml iReport file and I have set the queryString as follows:

```
<queryString language="XPath">
    <![CDATA[/reports/proposed_works_summary]]>
</queryString>
```

I have examined the demo https://github.com/fortesinformatica/jasper-rails-demo in detail and can't see what I am missing. A little help please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I resolved it doing a little update to jasper-rails because it does not supported on Rails 4.2, if you like can prove it [jasper-rails](https://github.com/ElamT/jasper-rails/)